# Is it possible to run selected javascript code in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Let say I want to see what is the value of this code, I want to run it. Can I select it and run that, and it would automatically import and execute all dependencies etc.

Answer (score -1):

VS Code is an `editor`, not a full IDE.

By itself, it run any code.

If you are writing for `node.js`, you may be able to call out to `node` and run things within a terminal window or, with the right plugin, turn on the debugger.

If you are writing code for the browser, then no, you cannot fully run that code inside VS code. You might want to use a tool that will watch for changes and reload the browser window.

Comment: if i could to run js code, even if it's meant for browser, with nodejs just by highlighting it and then running it somehow it'd be useful given it resolves all dependencies as much as possible.